# Bash for loop with paired variables

Tags: bash, loops, variables, for-loop

I have a directory with over 100 files that I have a list with a number that goes with each file. I want to run a for loop as such

```
numPairs="21 57 93... etc"
for filename in /directory/;
do
    $filename [numPairs[1]] > newfilename
done;
```

Is there a way to (say like in js, that's what I'm familiar with) call the numPairs item corresponding with the filename called in the for loop? Or would I be better creating another list with all of the filenames?

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to do in this line:
`$filename [numPairs[1]] > newfilename`

Comment: Is `numPairs` a string containing numbers delimited by whitespace? I'm also a bit befuddled by your code as it stands; please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is like:

```
numbers="21 57 93"
while IFS=$'\t' read -r num file; do
    echo "num=$num file=$file"
done < <(paste <(printf "%s\n" $numbers) <(printf "%s\n" /directory/*))
```